# System.Timers.Timer not firing when calling entity framework

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, windows-services

I have a windows service written in VB.NET using System.Timers.Timer instances to perform some periodic tasks. I have just migrated from .NET to .NET 4.5, using entity framework 4.3.1. The "elapsed" event handler of a timer fires up normally, as long as it does not using entity framework. When entity framework is used, the event handler does not fire. It just, doesn't fire. No exception thrown, no event log message, nothing. This didn't happen while using the .NET 4 version. Does anybody have any suggestions about it?

```
Dim testTimer As New System.Timers.Timer

Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    Try
        testTimer.Interval = 2 * 1000 * 60
        AddHandler testTimer.Elapsed, New System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf TestTimerMethod)
        testTimer.Enabled = True
  Catch ex As Exception
        'A method logging the respective exception
        LogException(ex)
    End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub TestTimerMethod()
    Try
        testTimer.Enabled = False
        UtilitiesProvider.GetUtilitiesProvider.LogWriter.Write("Start of method")

        'If I remove the next line, the event handler is fired as it should be...
        Dim dbContext As New DASTADbContext

        'mock some time consuming tasks
        Dim i = 0
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Log the exception
        UtilitiesProvider.GetUtilitiesProvider.LogException(ex)
    Finally
        testTimer.Enabled = True
    End Try

End Sub
```

Please, note the following :
1. I build the whole solution in x86 mode. I don't know if this is relevant.
2. I use VS2012 to build
3. I confirmed the above scenario using logging messages and also by debugging the whole service attaching to the respective process
4. I am referencing Entity Framework 4.3.1, built for runtime version .NET 4

Thank you in advance, 
Pantelis Natsiavas

EDIT : While this still remains an issue, I think I found who to blame. For some unexplainable reason, the Installshield Limited Edition used to create the windows service setup project, did not work as expected. When I used the primary output of windows service to create the setup project, for some unexplainable reason the Installshield LE added a reference to an older and now unused DLL which used Entity Framework 4. I suppose the bug occured because of referencing Entify Framework 4 and Entity Framework 4.3 at the same time. I have switched to VS2012, .NET 4.5 and InstallShield LE at the same time. Therefore, I mistakenly supposed that .NET 4.5 was to blame. I think that this should still be considered a bug, because I have never got an exception or something that would indicate I was doing something wrong. The timer, just did not fire the respective event handler(!).

Comment: I'd suggest you use `System.Threading.Timer` instead. It's .NET's canonical 'raw' timer and it isn't UI-centric like the other two timers.

Comment: Your protection against concurrent invocation does not work - you can still get two callback executions at once.; What exceptions are being logged? Please put a breakpoint at the critical line.